# PySpark: Extract multiple json elements from a string column in DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Source Dataframe:

```text
|Country|Emp_details(StringType)|
---------------------------------------------
|UK     |[{"name":"foo", "address":"someaddress"}]|
|US     |[{"name":"xyz", "address":"xyzaddress"},{"name":"abc", "address":"abcaddress"},..]|
```

Expected output Dataframe:

```text
|Country|name|address|
--------------------------  
|UK     |foo |someaddress|
|US     |xyz |xyzaddress|
|US     |abc |abcaddress|
```

Please note that `Emp_Details` can contain `1` or `n` number of json rows.

**Already Tried**

```
df.withColumn("empJson", from_json("Emp_details")).select(empJson.*).show()
```

Gives output values as null. It works if `Emp_details` has only 1 json row

Comment: Does the below post answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the schema for `from_json` function. In your case it's an array of structs. Then explode the resulting array and expand the inner structs using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("UK", """[{"name":"foo", "address":"someaddress"}]"""),
    ("US", """[{"name":"xyz", "address":"xyzaddress"},{"name":"abc", "address":"abcaddress"}]""")
], ["Country", "Emp_details"])

result = df.withColumn(
    "Emp_details",
    F.from_json("Emp_details", "array<struct<name:string,address:string>>")
).selectExpr(
    "Country", "inline(Emp_details)"
)

result.show()
#+-------+----+-----------+
#|Country|name|    address|
#+-------+----+-----------+
#|     UK| foo|someaddress|
#|     US| xyz| xyzaddress|
#|     US| abc| abcaddress|
#+-------+----+-----------+
```